# Send push data to background app

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I would like to send data to my app, when it is runs in the background. I know its possible to  let the iphone do some background tasks, but is it also possible receive data from a server when the iPhone is in the background. So that when the iPhone receives this data, i can change the behaviour of the 'background' app.

I am also aware of push notification, but what i mean is that the user wont be notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible, there are 3 background apps allowed by apple. Those are VOIP, audio and location based apps.

There is no other way to push data to an app other then push notifitcaions. but your app only receive the notification when the opens the notification.

The only other thing you can do is poll if the server has any new data for your app, but you can't really do this while in the background.